# How to configure the keybinddings of "most", a pager in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, pager

I've recently discovered the pager "most". `most` can make the manpages colorful and I like it. I want to change some of its bound keys and from the manpage of `most` I found out it's possible to do that. But I don't think the manpage ([link](https://linux.die.net/man/1/most)) has described precisely. In the **CONFIGURATION FILE SYNTAX** section of the manpage, **function-name** is mentioned but how do I know all the function names?

Here is a picture of the manpage of `most`

I raised this question in stackoverflow first and was told that it's a better choice to post the question here. Any help will be appreciated!.

---

Update:
OS:ubuntu 16.04

the way I install most: apt-get

[image]

Comment: How did you install `most`? What Unix/Linux are you using? at least in Debian based systems, the `most` package appears to place some example configuration files in `/usr/share/doc/most/` - in particular, the file `/usr/share/doc/most/most-fun.txt` lists the functions that may be used in custom keymaps

Comment: sorry for not listing the relevant information. You comments helps! And I know how to configure the keys at will. Thanks @steeldriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering [from the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396950/how-to-configure-the-keybinddings-of-most-a-pager-in-linux#comment708501_396950):

> in Debian based systems, the most package appears to place some example configuration files in `/usr/share/doc/most/` - in particular, the file `/usr/share/doc/most/most-fun.txt` lists the functions that may be used in custom keymaps.